# Difference between spent and spend

Tags: grammar

we never happened to have a lot of time **spend** together

we never happened to have a lot of time **spent** together

Which is correct?

Comment: The second is correct. The first needs a _to_ before _spend_ because it's an infinitive; _spent_ is a past participle here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct. It depends on the context. The first sentence implies that there was an *intention* (by using the 'to'- infinitive) and the second just emphasises the fact, in the past.

Comment: Sorry about this: since you posted this, I rolled back an edit to the question that I felt changed what it was about. The original poster did not have "to" in the first sentence.